Show that a regular class 1 graphs cannot contain an unmatchable edge.
We call an edge in a graph unmatchable if it is not contained in any perfect matching.
Then how to show that a regular class 1 graphs cannot contain an unmatchable edge?
I know th definition of regular graph, and graph of class 1, but didn't grasp where I should start from. Could anyone help me?

If $G$ is class $1$, we can color the edges with $\Delta(G)$ colors. For any edge $e\in E(G)$, can you use this coloring to find a perfect matching which contains $e$?
